# Postfix: Can I configure it to *not* include original email on undeliverable?

Tags: smtp, mail-transport-agent, postfix

The Postfix server is used *only* for mail-relay; in the office back-end, we use hMailServer. Some hMailServer users have their emails auto-forwarded to their BlackBerry account. Sometimes, they changed their BlackBerry operator without informing IT Dept. As a result, the auto-forward (handled by Postfix) failed, and a notification is sent (by Postfix) back to the user's account, which gets re-forwarded to the (no longer active) BlackBerry account, another failure, and ... well, you get the idea: A mailing loop.

I need to prevent this from happening. For complex reasons, we can't change our current setup of a separate internal mail server and the cloud-based Postfix mail-relay. So, I must either reconfigure Postfix or use some other mail-relay system that can be configured as such.

Answer (score 1):

Based on the title, I think the [bounce_size_limit](http://www.postfix.org/postconf.5.html#bounce_size_limit) option might help.  Try setting it to `0`.

Based on the question body, I think you need something else.

Is this what's happening?

```
1. hMail ---> Postfix (OK)
2. Postfix ---> BlackBerry (Fails)
3. Postfix ---> hMail (OK)
4. hMail ---> Postfix (loop)
etc.
```

If so, you could append a header to the message as it's being forwarded at step 2, then see if that header is present at step 4.